# React-Select Creatable prevent user from entering additional options if length of selection is reached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Currently I have a `Createable` component that has a dropdown menu and users can also freely enter any new value. However I want to disable creating new values if the maximum number is reached.

Here I used a custom menulist component to hide the dropdown (There is still a visible small line here beneath the component tho). But the user can still type, in the input. Is there any way to disable this specifically and not disable the whole component since they should still be able to delete selections.

```
const CustomMenuList = (props: any) => value?.length === 5 ? null : <components.MenuList {...props} />;
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to a working CodeSandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is generally correct but you need to apply it to the `Menu` component which is the container for `MenuList`, that's why you still see something when you hide `MenuList`

```
import { components } from 'react-select';

const CustomMenu = ({ children, ...props }) =>
  props.options.length === 5 ? null : (
    <components.Menu {...props}>{children}</components.Menu>
  );

<Select
  components={{
    Menu: CustomMenu,
  }}
/>
```

As for disabling the input, just follow the same logic and override the input's `disabled` attribute when options reach 5.